# Force clickhouse to reset offset of kafka engine table

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

I have a kafka topic and a Created a `MergeTree` Table and a `Kafka` Table and a `Materialized` view to get data from topic .
I need to consume message from earliest offset. My new consumer group offset set to latest message. But I can't find any setting to change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot reset the offset for the consumer group using ClickHouse. However I think you can achieve the same result in two ways:

1. Recreate the Kafka table with a different consumer group name using the `kafka_group_name` setting when [creating the table](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/kafka#creating-a-table).
2. Set the offset using `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`. After quickly searching for [how to do it](https://www.bigdatainrealworld.com/how-to-change-or-reset-consumer-offset-in-kafka/), I think the following command should work after using the correct host and group name: `kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafka-host:9092 --group my-group --reset-offsets --to-earliest  --topic sales_topic --execute`

Comment: second option is better here. using different group name will work for once only and not optimal if we want to reset offset again. not better if to drop/recreate table in clickhouse.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmadMujtaba Yes, you are right. Even though if it is a one time only things and the consumer group name is flexible, it might be faster. It depends on what they actually need.

Comment: For second option - you need to detach the all consumers ( kafka engines ) with that consumer group before resetting offsets, otherwise Kafka won't let you do it.